# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/enterprise/context/spi/Contextual when switching to jakarta dependencies

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle, junit, jakarta-migration

I am working on upgrading an application to Spring Boot 3.0, which also involves many javax -> jakarta dependency changes. I am still getting a failure compiling a test. I can't seem to hunt down where the javax dependency is coming from. Here's the error:

```
CdiServiceDiscoveryTest > initializationError FAILED
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/enterprise/context/spi/Contextual
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:3373)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3578)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:2271)
        at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
        at org.junit.vintage.engine.discovery.DefensiveAllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder$DefensiveAnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(DefensiveAllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:114)
        at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
        at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:70)
        at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:37)
        at org.junit.vintage.engine.discovery.DefensiveAllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(DefensiveAllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:57)
        at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:70)
        at org.junit.vintage.engine.discovery.ClassSelectorResolver.resolveTestClass(ClassSelectorResolver.java:66)
        at org.junit.vintage.engine.discovery.ClassSelectorResolver.resolve(ClassSelectorResolver.java:47)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.discovery.EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.lambda$resolve$2(EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.java:135)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.tryAdvance(ArrayList.java:1602)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:129)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:527)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:513)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:150)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:647)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.discovery.EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.resolve(EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.java:189)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.discovery.EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.resolve(EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.java:126)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.discovery.EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.resolveCompletely(EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.java:92)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.discovery.EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.run(EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.java:83)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.discovery.EngineDiscoveryRequestResolver.resolve(EngineDiscoveryRequestResolver.java:113)
        at org.junit.vintage.engine.discovery.VintageDiscoverer.discover(VintageDiscoverer.java:42)
        at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.discover(VintageTestEngine.java:64)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.discoverEngineRoot(EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.java:152)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.discoverSafely(EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.java:134)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.discover(EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.java:108)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.discover(EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.java:80)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discover(DefaultLauncher.java:110)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:118)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:93)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:88)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
        at jdk.proxy1/jdk.proxy1.$Proxy2.stop(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker$3.run(TestWorker.java:193)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.executeAndMaintainThreadName(TestWorker.java:129)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:100)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:60)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:56)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:113)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:65)
        at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
        at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)

        Caused by:
        java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.enterprise.context.spi.Contextual
            at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
            at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
            ... 59 more
```

And, my gradle.build file:

```
dependencies {
    implementation group: 'jakarta.platform', name: 'jakarta.jakartaee-api', version: '10.0.0'
    implementation  group: 'jakarta.enterprise', name: 'jakarta.enterprise.cdi-api', version: '4.0.1'

    testImplementation  "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.10.0"
    testImplementation  "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.10.0"
    testImplementation  "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.10.0"
    testImplementation  "org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:5.10.0"

    testImplementation  'org.apache.deltaspike.modules:deltaspike-test-control-module-api:1.9.6'
    testImplementation  'org.apache.deltaspike.core:deltaspike-core-impl:1.9.6'
    testImplementation  'org.apache.deltaspike.modules:deltaspike-test-control-module-api:1.9.6'
    testImplementation  'org.apache.deltaspike.modules:deltaspike-test-control-module-impl:1.9.6'
    testImplementation  'org.apache.deltaspike.cdictrl:deltaspike-cdictrl-weld:1.9.6'
    testImplementation  group: 'org.jboss.weld.se', name: 'weld-se-core', version: '5.1.1.SP2'
    testImplementation  group: 'jakarta.platform', name: 'jakarta.jakartaee-api', version: '10.0.0'
    testImplementation  group: 'jakarta.enterprise', name: 'jakarta.enterprise.cdi-api', version: '4.0.1'
}
```

Does anyone have any advice how to handle this error? Or how to use the jakarta variant of the dependency causing the error?

Answer (score 1):

The problem came from the `org.apache.deltaspike` which is still related to `javax` dependency in the `1.9.6` version.

The class which is not found is bundled in the following gradle ref :

```
    implementation  group: 'javax.enterprise', name: 'cdi-api', version: '2.0'
```

but now with jakarta migration, you're targeting :

```
    implementation  group: 'jakarta.enterprise', name: 'jakarta.enterprise.cdi-api', version: '4.0.1'
```

From what I can see, the project team is currently working on jakarta migration on a new v2 version (see deltaspike parent [pom.xml](https://github.com/apache/deltaspike/blob/master/deltaspike/parent/pom.xml)) with targeting jdk11 as baseline.

You should be able to use a SNAPSHOT to validate the migration process but I'd wait for a true release of deltaspike components before moving to jakarta.